# I keep getting map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { checkRef } from "./firebase";

function Dashboard() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
  let hi = [];
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    checkRef.on("value", snapshot => {
      let items = snapshot.val();
      let newState = [];
      for (let tracker in items) {
        newState.push({
          reason: items[tracker].reason,
          teacher: items[tracker].teacher
        });
      }
      setCount({ items: newState });
    });
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    // checkRef.on('value',(snapshot) => {
    //     console.log(snapshot.val())
    // })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>

        {count.items.map(item => {
        return <h1>{item.reason}</h1>;
        })}

    </div>
  );
}
export default Dashboard;
```

I am trying to return each item as an h1 after getting the item but i keep getting the error ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I apoligize i AM new to web dev and trying to learn. I have spent way to much time with no results. thanks

Comment: did you console api response data?

Answer (score 2):

Problem lies with your initalization of count.

For the very first render your count state variable doesn't contain any property named items. hence it fails.
your state variable is getting items prepery only after useEffect which excutes after first render.

based on your useeffct code, you should initialize count state variable with an object like follwing,

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState({items:[]});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `useEffect` is not calling the call back function (the one you defined).
You could try initializing the `count.items` to be an array
Or make sure that `useEffect` calls the callback function

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix your issue is simply do this:

```
{
  count && count.items && count.items.map( item => {
    // do something with the item
  })
}
```